# iFrame submit form, event listener

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a form inside an IFrame, and when I'm submitting it some content displays in it.
I need some event listener, which tells me that the iframe was submitted and the content loaded.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this event while submitting form

```
$("iframe").load(function(){
    var response = this.document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML;
    alert(response);
});
```